# GPU computing without X?

Tags: ubuntu, gpu

I am attempting to run GPU computation software on Ubuntu Server 12.04 without X since this box is going to be a dedicated computation machine. However the last requirement "Without X" is proving to be very problematic.

I have a ATI Radeon HD 5770 hooked up right now. Installed the x64 drivers from AMD's website by having it generate the correct debian packages. Ran `sudo aticonfig --initial --adapter=all` and rebooted. However it doesn't seem like its working

```
adam@adamcrunch:~$ DISPLAY=:0 fglrxinfo
Error: unable to open display (null)
adam@adamcrunch:~$ sudo aticonfig --list-adapter
* 0. 01:00.0 ATI Radeon HD 5700 Series

* - Default adapter
```

My software is also having issues as it just won't use the GPU for computation and tries to use the CPU.

I know during my initial install with Xubuntu that the card works and I can do GPU computation on it. However is it possible to do it on a headless server without X?

I can provide more information if needed

Comment: Take a look at Xvfb or something similar.

Comment: may be `env DISPLAY=:0 fglrxinfo`?

Comment: @Serge Tried that as normal user and root, same result

Comment: @nsg I didn't know such things existed. I will give xvfb a try then

Comment: @TheLQ Xvfb wouldn't help: that's an X server backed by memory. You need an X server that talks to the video card. There's no reason not to run an X server, even if you don't have a monitor plugged in.

Comment: @Gilles I was (maybe overcompensating) for general overhead of running a GUI on a server

Comment: @TheLQ You don't need to run a GUI environment, just the X server. For a machine where you're going to do heavy computation, even if the GPU is doing most of the work, an X server is negligible overhead.

Answer (score 6):

AMD's implementation of OpenCL requires that:

1. An X server be running on at least one of the AMD video cards in the system.
2. Your compute jobs must run within that X server.

If this is something you can't possibly do, then you should consider using different hardware, such as NVIDIA.